# catch data-attribute after jQuery selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am unable to catch the data-attribute after the applying jQuery UI select menu on it.

How is it possible to get the data?

HTML:

```
<select class="drpmnu">

         <option data-timings="something1">(01)</option>

         <option data-timings="something2">(02)</option>

</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(".drpmnu").selectmenu({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        console.log($(this).data('timings'));
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/hicura/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the selectmenu itself, not the object in it. You need to use `ui.item` for that:

```
$(".drpmnu").selectmenu({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        console.log($(ui.item.element).data('timings'));
    }
});
```